# How to make lowercase day names with fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the JQuery plugin FullCalendar and I want to know how to make the day names *lower case*. No matter how I format them they stay *upper case*.

I've scoured the documentation and tried these settings:

```
    columnFormat: 'ddd',
    dayNames: ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'],
    dayNamesShort: ['su', 'm', 'tu', 'w', 'th', 'f', 'sa'],
```

It just keeps displaying every character as upper case. Anyone know how to do this? If you need more information, I'm happy to oblige.

Comment: is there any css applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to change to way it looks when rendered add this to a css file with high priority:

```
.fc-view-container *{
    text-transform: lowercase !important;
}
```